# Where is the IIS 6 SMTP badmailfrom list?

Tags: iis-6, smtp

One of our applications started erroring out and a result was that hundreds of error emails were being sent in matter of seconds. This got the email sender (seems to be just the from address, not the IP) banned. We use the IIS 6 SMTP server. This is the entry from the bad mail file:

Diagnostic-Code: smtp;553 sorry, your envelope sender is in my badmailfrom list (#5.7.1)

I would like to remove the email sender from the list, but I cannot find it. I search the web for the location, but I didn't turn up anything.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error although recorded on the server hosting IIS actually originated from our 3rd Party email host. The email address being used to send the email was actually blocked from the email host. Calling them and getting them to remove the email address from their block list resolved this issue.